# HTML layout object doesn't work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I quite new with Django Crispy Form and I have tried to add a HTML object in my form but it's not working. All the other elements are rendered but not the HTML.

This is my form:

**forms.py**

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Fieldset, HTML

class MyUserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['title', 'privacy_disclaimer_accepted']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_method = 'post'
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
    helper.field_class = 'col-sm-6'
    helper.form_error_title = 'Form Errors'
    helper.error_text_inline = True
    helper.help_text_inline = True
    helper.html5_required = True
    helper.form_tag = False
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset('Information', 'title'),
        Fieldset('Privacy Statement',
                 HTML("""
                    <div id="iframe" class="mt-5">
                        <h6>Notice/Disclaimer:</h6>
                        <div class="privacy-policy">
                            {% if privacy_disclaimer %}
                                {{ privacy_disclaimer }}
                            {% else %}
                                {% include "registration/privacy_policy.html" %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 """),
         'privacy_disclaimer_accepted', )
    )
```

I have a basic HTML file, where I have the normal html, header and body tags.
This is the HTML registration page:

**register.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Create an account{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="registration-page">
    <h3 class="text-center">Create an account</h3>
    <div class="registration-page__form">

            {% if form.errors %}
            {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
                {{ form_myuser|crispy }}
                <br/>
                <div class="text-right">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn--action"  value="Create the account">
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT:**

**views.py**

```
class RegisterView(View):
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'

    def _get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        privacy_disclaimer = ''
        context['privacy_disclaimer'] = privacy_disclaimer
        if kwargs:
            context.update(kwargs)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        extra_context = {
            'form_myuser': MyUserRegistrationForm(),
        }
        context = self._get_context_data(**extra_context)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: Show the view. Are you sure you have both `form` and `form_myuser`?

Comment: Yes, I do @DanielRoseman. I update the context with the `form_myuser` in the method `_get_context_data` in the Registration View that I have. The template isn't broken,everything is rendered but not the HTML layout object.

Comment: Please show that view.

Comment: It's there! Check the post again. @DanielRoseman

Comment: What's this `HTML` object exactly ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers HTML: A very powerful layout object. Use it to render pure html code. In fact it behaves as a Django template and it has access to the whole context of the page where the form is being rendered. This layout object doesn’t accept any extra parameters than the html to render, you cannot set html attributes like in Div. (from crispy-forms documentation)

Comment: @JefersonM the question was : where does this come from. There's no import in your code snippet.

Comment: I added the import @brunodesthuilliers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue and the problem was the form loading.
I was loading it in the wrong way.
Instead of this `{{ form_myuser|crispy }}` I have to use this code `{% crispy form_tolauser %}`.